# Click event firing so many times on touchend on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios7

I created this fiddle and when I run it on iOS (I tested on iOS7), click event is fired a lot of times (around 15 - 20 times) on a single tap. But if I hold my finger for a brief moment before releasing it, click event does not fire at all. Why does it fire lots of click events in the first case, and why not at all in the second case?

```
parent.addEventListener("touchend", function () {
    console.log("parent is touched");

    parent.addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("parent is clicked");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5hsnx/

[image]

I know this is not really a useful piece of code in real life, but I was trying to figure out why this happens.

Comment: I think it is because you need a touchstart first?-) https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Comment: What do I need a touchstart for?

Comment: Don't know, just skimmed over the article. Seems the program gets "disturbed" if `touchstart` is not there...?

Comment: I read the documentation, but I could not find anywhere that says the program gets disturbed without touchstart. Which section of the documentation are you referring to?

Comment: At all. They never give examples with `touchend` before referencing `touchstart`. I might be wrong, as I said, just skimmed through. Have you tried? Just want to help here in comments. Good Luck btw!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding a new click event listener each time `touchend` fires, so over time, you'll see more and more events fired in the log.